# Data factory Use query to create json

Tags: json, azure-data-factory

I have this situation where I need to create a json based on metadata and I have run into a problem with creation.

I use a database for making the query and it looks like this:
Use query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
'
{
"entries": [
{
"example": true,
"url": "https://xxxxxx.core.windows.net/xxxxx/',
'@{pipeline().Pipeline}',
'/',
 '@{
 concat(
item().name
)
}',
'"
}]}'
)AS json
```

The result will look like this:

```
{"json":"\n{\n\"entries\": [\n{\n\"example\": true,\n\"url\": \"https://xxxxx.core.windows.net/xxxxx/yyyyyyy/table.aaaa.20200914003004.ooo.20200914003004.false.json\"\n}]}"}
```

**How to a get rid of the line feed \n ?**

Also tried this:

> SELECT
> CONCAT('{"entries":[{"example":true,"url":"https://xxxxxx.core.windows.net/yyyyyyyy/','@{Pipeline().Pipeline}','/','@{concat(item().name)}','"}]}'
> ) AS json

The end result should look like this

```
>    {
>       "entries": [
>         {
>           "example": true,
>           "url": "https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/yyy/asasadasdek/asdaedasd"
>         }
>       ]
>     }
```

**Update**

Tasks: Get file names from blob, the names and copy names to one json file

[image: Get file names from blob, the names and copy names to one json file]

Copy source activity should create a format like this

```
    SELECT CONCAT(
'
{
"entries": [
{
"example": true,
"url": "https://xxxxxx.core.windows.net/xxxxx/',
'@{pipeline().Pipeline}',
'/',
 '@{
 concat(
item().name
)
}',
'"
}]}'
)AS json
```

But it still has the problem with \n

Comment: You can try `@json()` function in ADF to convert it to json type ?

Comment: Hi @kaarel, please correct me if I understand you wrong in the answer.

Comment: It's not a straight forward thing. I will get back about that when I have a solution :)

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**
So we can change the query to `SELECT CONCAT(' '@{CONCAT(activity('variable1'))}' ') AS JSON`. Then we can remove the `\n` character.

Comment: Very good example! this doesn't solve the problem really. 

What I'm trying to do is get metadata from blob, filenames and then write the file names to a json file.

1. Getfilenames  = childitems
2. set variable where I use Variables Array1 @activity('Getfilenames').output.childItems (variable idea from you)
3. sql and sink

And now I have the sql copy where I try to copy all the names in to json, which works, but the line feed escapees because it will produce string

Comment: Due to the information I can get on your question is limited, here I only do type conversion to remove line feed escapees, you can add the details and requirements of the question or add a new question, I will try my best to help you.

Comment: I have made it to this: 

1. SELECT  CONCAT('

'@{CONCAT(activity('variable1'))}'

') AS JSON

Comment: Nice, you solved the problm. I've also updated the answer. If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Very thanks!